# Problems using alias with typescript project

Tags: typescript, webpack, google-cloud-functions

I am struggling with setting up the alias functionality in a Cloud Function Typescript project.

I basically want to be able to simply do this:

`import { ROLES } from '@config/roles"` - 'roles' is a ts file which exports a constant

This only works if I create an index file in the config folder which does `export * from "./roles"` , then I am able to do `import { ROLES } from '@config'`. If i don't have the index file and try to import the ts file directly, I get following error during the build phase:

> Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module '/functions/config/roles'

My problem is that there are multiple locations where the error could come from, but I seem to misunderstand how the three sections play together:

**tslint.json**

```
 "no-implicit-dependencies": [
      true,
      ["@", "@model", "@services", "@utils", "@config"]
    ],
```

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"],
      "@model": ["model"],
      "@services": ["services"],
      "@utils": ["utils"],
      "@config": ["config"]
    }
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

**module-alias**

I use [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) to map the typescript aliases into the compiled js files during the build process (I have an index file that goes through all the folders and automatically builds function names based on folder and file names)

```
 "_moduleAliases": {
    "@": ".",
    "@model": "lib/model",
    "@services": "lib/services",
    "@utils": "lib/utils",
    "@config": "lib/config"
  }
```

With the above settings, it says:

> Cannot find module '@config/roles' or its corresponding type
> declarations.ts(2307)

I have tried every possible combination of changing the parameters in all three sections, but I can't simply refer to a file inside a subfolder within one of the aliases, I always have to use barrel files.

I could use some help to sort out my config...

Comment: To start the investigation, are you following along any documentation?

Comment: I've found some setup information to move this along https://medium.com/@wcandillon/writing-cloud-functions-with-typescript-61d86e282752

Comment: @MrTech sorry, forgot to respond - you actually helped me to resolve my issue with your initial post. I was so stuck in troubleshooting mode that I forgot to just retrace the steps and follow a working tutorial. Found this one back then and once I worked through it, everything was ok: https://dev.to/larswaechter/path-aliases-with-typescript-in-nodejs-4353